# CORS issue for google scholars api

Tags: google-api

I am getting CORS issue while calling `http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=java`

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=java' from origin
> 'http://localhost:57013' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not
> allowed for a preflight request.

```
const GOOGLE_SCHOLAR_URL =
          'http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=java';
      final dio = Dio();
      final resp = await dio.get(GOOGLE_SCHOLAR_URL,
          options: Options(headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':
                'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token'
          }));
```

Comment: What is the language you are programming your application in?

Comment: flutter & dart ,added code snippet to question.